# Crear una función de WordPress cuando un usuario se registra

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Estoy pensando la manera de crear una función que se ejecute luego de que un usuario se registre y luego tomar sus datos para enviarlos a través de una URL en una nueva pestaña, pero no estoy muy segura. Hasta el momento este es el código que he creado:

```html
<?php
function shapeSpace_first_user_login($user_login, $user) {
$new_user = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', true);
if ($new_user) {
 update_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', '0');

 global $current_user
 get_currentuserinfo();
 $titulo = $current_user->title;
 $nombre = $current_user->user_firstname;
 $apellido = $current_user->user_lastname;
 $institucion = $current_user->institution;
 $direccion = $current_user->addr1;
 $ciudad = $current_user->city;
 $pais = $current_user->country;
 $correo = $current_user->user_email;
 $correo_anterior = $correo;
 $contrasena = $current_user->password; // ¿La contraseña está encriptada?

 if (empty($titulo) || empty($institucion) || empty($city)) {
   $titulo = "Mr";
   $institucion = "Unknown institution";
   $ciudad = "Unknown city";
 }

 $url_registro = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/add_registered_user.asp?title=" .$title. "&first_name=" .$nombre. "&&last_name=" .$apellido. "&institution=" .$institucion. "&address=" .$direccion. "&city=" .$ciudad. "&country=" .pais. "&email=" .$correo. "&password=" .contrasena. "&previous_email=" .$correo_anterior.;
 $url_acceso = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/login_integration.asp?email=" .$correo. "&password=" .$contrasena.;

?>

 <form action="<?php echo $url_registro ?>" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="enviar_usuario">
 </form>

 <form action="<?php echo $url_acceso ?>" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="login_usuario">
 </form>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("enviar_usuario").submit();
 }

 function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("login_usuario").submit();
 }
 </script>



<?php
}
}
add_action('wp_login', 'shapeSpace_first_user_login', 10, 2);
?>
```

Por otro lado también quiero saber si es posible crear una función cuando el usuario cambia su contraseña o actualiza sus datos.

Cualquier sugerencia es agradecida.

Comment: Quieres registrar al usuario en un segundo sitio cuando se registre en tu wordpress?

Comment: Así es y esa fue la forma que me dió el programador de la otra web.

Answer (score 0):

La API de Wordpress tiene ya filtros para todo eso. En realidad, no hay casi nada que necesitemos que WP no lo tenga. Se recomienda, antes de querer reinventar la rueda, mirar [todo lo que hay en la API de WP](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/).

**Nota:** este código debe añadirse al archivo functions.php del tema actual o al archivo del child theme, en el caso de frameworks como Thesis, Genesis, etc.

1. Redirección para cuando un usuario se registra. Para eso existe: [registration_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_redirect)

Ejemplo de uso:

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'my_redirect_home' );
function my_redirect_home( $registration_redirect ) {
    return home_url('quiero-que-vayas-a-esta-url');
}
```

*Cambia lo que hay dentro de home_url()...

---

2. Ser notificado cuando el usuario cambia su contraseña: te puedes valer de  [personal_options_update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update) y [edit_user_profile_update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update)

Este ejemplo te manda al email cualquier cambio que haga un usuario. Si sólo te interesa el email lo puedes adaptar.

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'notificar_admin_on_update' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update','notificar_admin_on_update' );

function notificar_admin_on_update(){
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if (!current_user_can( 'administrator' )){// no notifica si quien cambia es el admin
        $to = 'admin@email.com'; //cambiar por tu email
        $subject = 'Un usuario ha actualizado su perfil';
        $message = "El usuario : " .$current_user->display_name . " actualizó los siguientes datos de su perfil:\n";
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message .= $key . ": ". $value ."\n";
        }
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias me servirá como código base.